# Execute HTML5 data- string as JavaScript (without eval)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following div:

`<div id="foo" data-callback="function(){console.log(1)}"></div>`

I want to be able to execute the div's callback string as a JavaScipt function like this:

`($('#foo').data('callback'))()`

But this obviously won't work. Is there any way to do this?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXfaw/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest not storing code as a `data-` attribute.  Make a function, then just store the function name as the attribute.

```
<script>
function callbackA(){
    console.log(1)
}
</script>
<div id="foo" data-callback="callbackA"></div>
```

Then you can do `window[$('#foo').data('callback')]()`.

EDIT: If you don't want to do this, you can also make use of the `onclick` event (or any (built-in) event for that matter).

```
<div id="foo" onclick="console.log(1)"></div>
```

Then you can use `.prop` to get the event (as a function), and then use it.

```
var callback = $('#foo').prop('onclick'); // get function
$('#foo').removeProp('onclick'); // remove event
callback();  // use function
```

Comment: I can't really do this. I'm developing a plugin and I want people to be able to add custom callbacks to certain elements in a simple and easy way.

Comment: This is a "simple an easy way".  Make a global function, and set the attribute to its name, simple.  Why can't you do that?

Comment: Yes but I don't want them to have to add another script tag to their page. Ideally I want a JavaScript solution for the HTML example I gave to work.

Comment: @DC_: Check the edit to my answer.  You can use the `onclick` event to attach a function to the DOM element.  You can then use jQuery to grab that function and use it.

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty interesting. It seems a bit too hackish though.

Comment: @DC_: It's the only other possibility (I could think of), short of using `eval`.

Comment: @DC_: It may be "hackish", which is why I first suggested *not* storing code as a HTML attribute.

Comment: @rocket I guess you've been right all along. I'm going to do what you suggested first with some slight modifications. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

One, potentially crazy :), solution would be to use [js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js/). This would be more secure than `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can alter the html to

```
<div id="foo" data-callback="{console.log(1)}"></div>
```

then you can do

```
new Function($('#foo').data('callback'))()
```

---

But why do you ***need*** to do it that way ?

Comment: need to do because you can save callbacks on form-submits.

Answer (score 0):

What you have can be done using `eval`, but **eval is evil**.

**Edit:**

And some modifiction is required to your HTML,

```
<div id="foo" data-callback="(function (){console.log(1)})"></div>
```

JS

```
eval($('#foo').data('callback'))();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/CXfaw/5/)

Comment: Read the title: Execute HTML5 data- string as JavaScript (**without eval**)?

Comment: @DC_ Any conversion of string expression to a javascript object (function) will be using eval. You cannot evaluate a string without `eval`.

Comment: @Vega: that is almost true, except for property access using brackets. Therefore, Rocket's answer does allow you to call a function without relying on eval

Comment: @JuanMendes I agree and I even upvoted Rockets answer because it is the best alternative, but Rocket's answer is not same as what OP had posted which is basically evaluating a string expression as a function and I was stating that It is not possible without eval.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor, however, you will need a string containing only your statements. You can either parse your existing string or even better, if you can modify the value of that data attribute at the source. Then you would do

```
var fn = new Function($("#foo").data("callback"));
fn();
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXfaw/1/)**